# IIS 8.5/Windows 2012 R2 Application Pool HTML Rendering Is Breaking Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, clr, iis-8

We've upgraded a rather large mission critical web application to run on Windows 2012 R2/IIS 8.5 up from Windows 2003/IIS 6.

The application framework is 3.5 and the IIS 8.5 application was originally set to CLR 2.0 but changed to 4.0 when it was discovered a critical piece of functionality (hashtable ordering) was not working as expected.

This fixed the hashtable issue, however now it seems that the HTML is being rendered differently which is breaking javascript functionality and css.

For example:

[image: Winmerge Diff - CLR 2.0 Left - CLR 4.0 Right]
The left side of the image (clr2.0 app pool) shows the properly rendered control with the required 'ctl00$' prefix, however the right side of the image (clr4.0 app pool) shows that the HTML is rendered incorrectly, which occurs throughout the page, thus breaking our needed Javascript functionality.

Here's another example:

[image: Another Example]
MS suggests upgrading the whole app to the 4.0 Framework, but the JS still seems to remain broken since the HTML is still rendering the same.

Here's a small snippet of code that adds a client side Javascript event to an asp.net Link control in the .cs codebehind:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = e.Item.FindControl("btnlnk2") as LinkButton;
            DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            if (lnk != null && row!=null)
            {
                lnk.Text = row["Linktext"].ToString();
                lnk.OnClientClick = "return SetStatus('" + cgridNumbered.ClientID + "_ctl" + "','" + row["Name"].ToString() + "')";
            }
        }
```

Here's the actual Javascript in the aspx page:

```
function SetStatus(ddTarget,strLnk) {            
        var ctrl = document.getElementById(ddTarget);            
        var str = strLnk;            
        var chkNameLast = "_ddlNextMaterialStatus";
        var i = 3;
        var tempchkobj = document.getElementById(ddTarget + "02" + chkNameLast);

        var intIdx = -1;
        var intMax = tempchkobj.options.length;
        for (var intOpt = 0; intOpt < intMax; intOpt++) {
            if (tempchkobj.options[intOpt].text == strLnk) {
                intIdx = intOpt; // this is the index
                intOpt = intMax; // escape the loop
            }
        }
       //more code..
        return false;
    }
```

When running the application using the 4.0 CLR at the point that this event is fired, the value of ddTarget is "MainContentPlaceHolder_cgridNumbered_ctl"

But the HTML is rendered like this ():

```
<a onclick="return SetStatus(&#39;MainContentPlaceHolder_cgridNumbered_ctl&#39;,&#39;Confirmed&#39;);" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_DataList1_btnlnk2_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$DataList1$ctl00$btnlnk2&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Confirm All</a>
```

Where it seems the single quote is being translated to its HTML equivalent:

```
&#39;
```

And our Javascript breaks since it cannot find this DOM object.

When we switch the Application Pool clr to 2.0, the HTML renders correctly like this:

```
 <a onclick="return SetStatus('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_cgridNumbered_ctl','Confirmed');" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataList1_ctl00_btnlnk2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$DataList1$ctl00$btnlnk2','')">Confirm All</a>
```

And our Javascript works as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help with this, we've been working on it for a month now.

Comment: "critical piece of functionality (hashtable ordering) " :) that is a joke, right? (as hash tables have no ordering)

Comment: You may want to show code that generates HTML that is different between versions. It is very hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response.  I think your suggestion is to show the code that generates the HTML.  The code that generates the HTML is identical since the only thing that changes is the IIS Application pool which changes from 2.0 to 4.0

Comment: Since you can't show [MCVE] (so someone can guess environment differences) and obviously can't show environment difference themselves I doubt you'll be able to get any useful answers.

Comment: I edited the question to include some additional detail.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened Pages and Controls setting in IIS

[image: Pages and Controls]

Changed settings to the following:

[image]

CSS and Javascript are working now and HTML is rendering as expected:

[image]